# Extract Velocities from Qualified EntityValue output

Tags: entity

I have following statement:

```
EntityValue["Planet", "VelocityAroundSun", {"Date" -> 
DateObject[{2020, 2, 19}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.]}]
```

and get the required output in a form I don't understand, see below.  I want to extract the list with velocities from this output into a simple list. How can I do that ?

```
{("Date" -> 
     DateObject[{2020, 2, 19}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.])[{Quantity[
     55.9314, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")], 
    Quantity[35.1845, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")], 
    Quantity[30.1244, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")], 
    Quantity[24.0561, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")], 
    Quantity[13.0407, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")], 
    Quantity[9.14217, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")], 
    Quantity[6.57181, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")], 
    Quantity[5.44866, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")]}]}[3]
```

Comment: You have incorrect syntax for an `EntityProperty` qualifier.  You should have `EntityValue["Planet", 
 EntityProperty["Planet", 
  "VelocityAroundSun", {"Date" -> 
    DateObject[{2020, 2, 19}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.]}]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the property with `Dated`

```
EntityValue["Planet", Dated["VelocityAroundSun", Today]]
```

[image]

or use `EntityProperty[...]` to specify the dated property:

```
EntityValue["Planet", EntityProperty["Planet", "VelocityAroundSun", {"Date" -> Today}]]
```

> same result

Property values on a different date:

```
EntityValue["Planet", Dated["VelocityAroundSun", DatePlus[Today, {1, "Month"}]]]
```

[image]

Use `QuantityMagnitude` to get the numbers:

```
QuantityMagnitude @ EntityValue["Planet", Dated["VelocityAroundSun", Today]]
```

> {125227., 78704.8, 67387.4, 53808.5, 29171.1, 20450.4, 14700.7, 12188.3}

or use `QuantityMagnitude` as third argument in `EntityValue`:

```
EntityValue["Planet", "VelocityAroundSun", QuantityMagnitude]
```

> same result

Use the third argument of `EntityValue` to get the result as an `Association` object:

```
EntityValue["Planet", Dated["VelocityAroundSun", DatePlus[Today, {1, "Month"}]], 
   "EntityAssociation"]
```

[image]

**Note:** Why are you getting *"a form I don't understand"*:

The third argument of `EntityValue` is used as a function that is applied to the result returned:

```
EntityValue["Planet", "VelocityAroundSun", foo]
```

[image]

Comment: Based on comments most simple seems: QuantityMagnitude@
 EntityValue["Planet", Dated["VelocityAroundSun", Today]]